# Static constant class member vs. literal for comparisons within a function?

Tags: c++

I have a member function that needs to compare a string object with a constant value to check for equality. The function will be called very often comparing unique string against the constant each time.

Is it more efficient to achieve this with a static constant for comparing against, eg:

```
//.h
class MyClass
{
    static const std::string fooBar;

  public:
    bool isFooBar(const std::string& str);
  //...
};

//.cpp
const std::string MyClass::fooBar = "FooBar";

bool MyClass::isFooBar(const std::string& str)
{
    if(fooBar == str)
    return true;

    return false;
}
```

Or should I just use a string literal, eg:

```
bool MyClass::isFooBar(const std::string& str)
{
    if("FooBar" == str)
    return true;

    return false;
}
```

I read that accessing static object is not so efficient, but now I cannot find the source. Is that true? I am confused to which tradeoff is better: static object access or construction of 6 byte string (with short string optimization) for each call to the method?

I really struggle with this kind of micro decisions. Will I improve as I become more experienced?

Thank you all.

Comment: And where do you think the string literal is stored? Most likely there won't be any difference at all...

Comment: Off-topic: Please don't write code such as `if(condition) return true; else return false;` – just have `return condition` instead.

Comment: Instead of 3 lines just write  return ( foobar == str);

Comment: Well won't the literal just be reconstructed each call to the function? Or am I missing a part of the picture here?

Comment: "String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program." (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Comment: Thank you very much @eike, found the part of the picture I was missing.

Comment: I would only suggest using a static member variable if you compare against this string in multiple places.  In that case it makes refactoring a lot easier.  If you only check the string in one place then there is no need for a variable.